# why we use FILE * instead of FILE for I/O

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, cross-platform, c99

Today I am learning things about Standard I/O of C. When I opened the stdio.h file found that:

```
typedef struct _iobuf FILE;
```

and when check the defination of struct _iobuf found that:

```
struct _iobuf {
    char *_ptr;
    int   _cnt;
    char *_base;
    int   _flag;
    int   _file;
    int   _charbuf;
    int   _bufsiz;
    char *_tmpfname;
};
```

To understand more, I have given descriptions about each don't whether it is correct or not

```
struct _iobuf {
    char *_ptr;      /* next character position */
    int   _cnt;      /* characters left */
    char *_base;     /* location of buffer */
    int   _flag;     /* File status flags */
    int   _file;
    int   _charbuf;   /*Data transfer buffer */
    int   _bufsiz;    /* Buffer size */
    char *_tmpfname;  /* Temporary file indicator */
};
```

Now having two questions in my mind?

Q1: Have I provided the correct Names and how structure help in I/O and if I add or delete any thing what would happen? Does that would work accordingly? Does the sequence provided here matters?

Q2: There is no pointer used here but why use FILE * for opening the File?

Answer (score 5):

> Have I provided the correct Names?

These are all internal details that are specific to the Microsoft implementation, and AFAIK, undocumented.

> if I add or delete any thing what would happen?

That would be really bad; you'd probably be causing **undefined behaviour**.

> There is no pointer used here but why use FILE * for opening the File?

Because from the point-of-view of your application code, the implementation details don't matter; `FILE *` is intended to be an [*opaque pointer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

Comment: If I want to create such my implementation what should i do

Comment: @vineet1982: Feel free to write your own implementation by using [PIMPL](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29).

Comment: How can I create my own implementation and do hiding

Comment: @vineet1982: Why on earth would you want to write your own implementation?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth As it would be safest thing to hide something from accessing

Comment: @AlokSave that is in C++, any such thing in C

Comment: @vineet1982: Pimpl can be used in C as well.

Comment: @vineet1982: WHy did you tagged the Q with visual-c++ and what Oli says above.

Comment: @vineet1982 You make no sense. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: @NikosC. I want to change things according to my needs

Comment: @vineet1982: Change what things?

Comment: @vineet1982 You still make no sense. You should clarify your question and mention exactly what you want to do.

Comment: To achieve the information hiding (encapsulation) aspect of Object-Oriented Programming using the C language

Comment: @NikosC. I want to achieve this but don't know how?

Comment: @vineet1982 You can't hide the `FILE` struct members. If your question is about how to hide members of structs you define yourself, that would be a different question.

Answer (score 4):

A1. Editing a standard header would result in undefined behaviour.

A2. Structs are usually passed as pointers in C to avoid copying. Also, it's meant to act as a handle or an opaque pointer.

Bigger question is why would want to do anything you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to all your questions:

[The Standard C Library by P.J. Plauger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099)